In the Vim editor, I want to enable Github Copilot manually and have it disabled by default
If one installs the Github Copilot software for the Vim editor, it enables the co-pilot by default, which could be seen as a privacy issue.
I want to disable the co-pilot by default and only enable it manually via :Copilot enable in the editor when needed.
How may I do that?

The co-pilot can be globally disabled with :Copilot disable.  This command may be executed automatically from the vimrc file (~/.vimrc or ~/.vim/vimrc or $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/vim/vimrc) using an autocmd command like so:
autocmd VimEnter * Copilot disable

The VimEnter event is triggered "after doing all the startup stuff".   The pattern * matches all filenames, so it always applies.
It is then a matter of running the command :Copilot enable whenever one wants to have inline suggestions from the co-pilot again.

I believe the option you're looking for is g:copilot_filetypes:
g:copilot_filetypes     A dictionary mapping file types to their enabled
                        status.  Most file types are enabled by default, so
                        generally this is used for opting out.
>
                        let g:copilot_filetypes = {
                              \ 'xml': v:false,
                              \ }
<
                        Disabling all file types can be done by setting the
                        special key "*".  File types can then be turned back
                        on individually.
>
                        let g:copilot_filetypes = {
                              \ '*': v:false,
                              \ 'python': v:true,
                              \ }

So add to your vimrc:
let g:copilot_filetypes = { '*': v:false }

And then enable it when needed.

For the "enable it when needed" bit, one would need to manually type in the corresponding command to enable the co-pilot for all file types or the current buffer's file type (which you would have to query with :set ft first). This would IMHO be more cumbersome than just giving the command :Copilot enable. It would also render one's setup of Copilot-enabled file types useless.

@Kusalananda are you saying that with this config, just doing :Copilot enable doesn't enable copilot?

Also there's the buffer-local b:copilot_enabled described right below this option which should be more convenient than looking up the buffer's file type

Exactly. With your suggestion, the co-pilot would still be disabled based on the file type of the current buffer matching that * pattern, even if you do :Copilot enable (it does not reset the g:copilot_filetypes structure).

And if you do let b:copilot_enabled = v:true in the buffer in which you want to enable it?

Then it is enabled in the current buffer. Sorry, I forgot to test that bit after seeing your previous comment.

Nice, so you can map it to some convenient shortcut or command and use it enable when needed
